# Font shape `LTJY3/SimSun(0)/m/sl' undefined

Tags: fonts, luatex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontset=none]{ctexart}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,wasysym}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso,frak=euler,bb=ams]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

    啊啊啊啊啊啊

\end{document}
```

When I compile this simple document, `lualatex` says:

```
Font shape `LTJY3/SimSun(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)  using `LTJY3/SimSun(0)/m/n' instead.
```

How did this happen? I did not use slanted characters!

SimSun（中易宋体） is a Chinese font which can be found on Windows

**Any explain about what `LTJY3/SimSun(0)/m/sl` means is welcome!**

Comment: "sl" means "slanted shape" which is a font shape for some normal font. You can try `\textsl{}` and `\textit{}` in the `article` document class in the default fonts to see the difference. For Chinese fonts, we usually set the italic shape font for the normal font (for example, SimSun, i.e., 宋体) to be KaiTi (楷体), while we usually set the slanted shape font to be nothing since it's usually not necessary.

Comment: I usually translate "the italic shape font" as "意体" (i.e., "意大利人发明的字体" because Niccolo Niccoli who first uses such a font is Italic) and "the slanted shape" as "斜体" although many people mistake "the italic shape font" for "斜体".

Answer (score 0):

Define an italic font for Chinese, for example:

```
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}[BoldFont=Noto Sans CJK SC Medium,ItalicFont=KaiTi]
```

Comment: In fact, we have already done such similar settings in the `ctex` package which is invoked in default by the `ctexart` document class.